# HTML5, Knockout url redirect function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, rest, knockout.js

I have created an HTML5 application which uses knockoutjs to make call to a restful service and get/post JSON messages. 
This is my first application using HTML5 so I am not sure how to implement a URL redirect.

In the application I have two html pages, one is a DataGrid page which shows all the data received by doing a get rest call. I have added a hyperlink to one the field in the display which I would like to use to redirect to the details page and make the rest call to get data for that particular id and display it in the editable page later would like to save the changes.

**UserGridPage.html**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:userList">
<tr>
<td><a data-bind="attr:{href: userInfoUrl()}, text:userInfoId"></a></td>
<td data-bind="text: UserName" ></td>
</tr>
```

**UserGridPage.js**

```
MyUserInfoViewModel = function () {
var self = this;
self.userList = ko.observableArray();
$.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/user/webresources/userinfo/").
        then(function (userinfos) {
            $.each(userinfos, function () {
                self.userList.push({
                           userInfoUrl:ko.observable('/USERUI/UserEntry.html#'+this.userInfoId),
                    userInfoId:ko.observable(this.userInfoId),
                    policyHolderEmail: ko.observable(this.policyHolderEmail),
                });
            });
        });
```

I would like to know how can UserEntry page would know which Id is getting passed to its page and also how would I make the rest call to have the Id passed to the restful URL.

Appreciate any help with code samples, links etc..

Thanks

Comment: are you looking to make a column in your grid a hyperlink and you want to redirect on click  to respective details page passing row id. let us know .

Comment: @supercool Yes you are correct, i am using making a column as hyperlink and upon clicking on it want to take the the user to the details page with all the data filled in...

Comment: ok please check the answer posted and i hope that helps . cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your userEntry.html, if you want to get the id value passed:

```
<script>
  var id = window.location.hash;
</script>
```

I remember firefox has a slightly different behaviour in that it decodes URL encoded characters in the fragment, so if you want the raw content, you can also consider using:

```
<script>
  var id = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be trying like this

**View :**

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>
        <a data-bind="attr: { href: id }, text: name,click:function(){alert(id)}"></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**ViewModel :**

```
var viewModel = {
    items: [{'id':1,'name':"one"},{'id':2,'name':"two"},{'id':3,'name':"three"}]        
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Sample working fiddle **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/WbxPm/216/)**

Comment: I tried this and it works...but I would like to have the click call a function on the viewmodel and pass the id as parameter to the function. Once I get that I can make the REST call based on the ID and get all the details for that particular Id...thanks

Answer (score -1):

Not sure how you can get the parameter from the URL with javascript, but if you are willing to use PHP you could get the Id parameter with $_REQUEST['Id'] an use it to generate your new REST call.

So your href would be something like "/USERUI/UserEntry.php?Id=5"

To use that variable in javascript on your UserEntry page you can do something like:

```
 <script>
    var id = <?php $_REQUEST['Id']; ?>

    //generate your restful query here.
 </script>
```

Comment: I am not very much familiar with PHP is there any way I could using JSP to do the same...

Comment: The question did not say what server tech they were using. Introducing PHP as a solution to a Javascript problem is not appropriate. It's also very simple to get the parameter from the URL with javascript. This is a poor answer

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to offer some guide on how to solve the problem.